2 OnEdits, but they reference different sheets
I have 2 separate sheets moving rows to 2 separate Completed Tabs on the same Worksheet via an OnEdit Function.  One works fine, if there are 2 it only runs the last function.
I've found some information on this, but they all are moving information from one sheet to 2 separate tabs, which doesn't fix it.
What I am trying to do: (Example file below)
If Column 21 on Main Tab is TRUE, move to Completed Tab
If Column 19 on Rework Tab is TRUE, move to Completed Reworks Tab
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T-rP6an4HeIufwm0eTHL_SDBkFSwpNrERnmHrVGYx2g/edit?usp=sharing

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. This is a very common question that has already been answered, but I can't find the original question for you now. I'm sorry. It might be closed as a duplicate later.

If you want feedback on a script please [edit] your question to include it.

The layout of the 'Main' and 'Completed' sheets differ, so it is a bit surprising that you want to move rows from one to the other and back as is.
Nevertheless, the code could use a little restructuring. Try this to get started:
'use strict';

/**
* Moves a row from one sheet to another.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function moveRow_(e) {
  try {
    const parameters = [
      { sheet: 'Main', column: 21, value: 'TRUE', targetSheet: 'Completed', action: sortTargetSheet_, },
      { sheet: 'Completed', column: 21, value: 'FALSE', targetSheet: 'Main', },
      { sheet: 'Rework', column: 19, value: 'TRUE', targetSheet: 'Completed Reworks', },
      { sheet: 'Completed Reworks', column: 19, value: 'FALSE', targetSheet: 'Rework', },
    ];
    let sheet, sheetName;
    const settings = parameters.find(p => p.value === e.value && p.column === e.range.columnStart && (sheetName = sheetName || (sheet = sheet || e.range.getSheet()).getName()) === p.sheet);
    if (!settings) return;
    const targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(settings.targetSheet);
    if (!targetSheet) throw new Error(`Cannot find sheet '${settings.targetSheet}'.`);
    targetSheet.appendRow([null]);
    const targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    e.source.toast('Moved the row.');
    if (settings.action) settings.action({ e, settings, sheet, targetSheet, targetRange });
  } catch (error) {
    e.source.toast(`${error.message} ${error.stack}`, 'Error in moveRow_(e)', 30);
    throw error;
  }
}


/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user manually edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.');
  moveRow_(e);
}


/**
* Sorts a sheet by column A.
*
* @param {Object} { e, targetSheet } An object with fields for an event object and a sheet.
*/
function sortTargetSheet_({ e, targetSheet }) {
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  e.source.toast('Sorting target sheet...', '', 3);
  targetSheet.sort(1);
}

The original function takes ~60 lines of code while the above only takes ~20. Debugging is much easier when the whole function fits in one screenful.
There was no sortCompleted() function in your script project so I threw in one.
See Clean Code JavaScript.

Thank you!
This worked!
The sheet structure was modified a few times so we have some column inconsistancy.  I have to back up some of the old stuff just to clean it up.  This spreadsheet is a bit of an experiment.

I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See What should I do when someone answers my question?
